# Google cloud regions for the projects(Personal/Official)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a doubt regarding regions in google cloud. If I my current location is in Australia I need to opt region near to me for a better performance or I can opt multiple locations. Bit confusing on the regions. Could someone explain on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regions: The main purpose is to host applications near to your users to reduce latency and availability .
Ask Question
Zones: Zone provides geo redundancy used mainly for availability inside regions.

Distribute your resources across multiple zones and regions to tolerate outages. Google designs zones to minimize the risk of correlated failures caused by physical infrastructure outages like power, cooling, or networking. Thus, if a zone becomes unavailable, you can transfer traffic to another zone in the same region to keep your services running. Similarly, you can mitigate the impact of a region outage on your application by running backup services in a different region.

To decrease network latency, you might want to choose a region or zone that is close to your point of service. For example, if you mostly have customers on the East Coast of the US, then you might want to choose a primary region and zone that is close to that area and a backup region and zone that is also close by.

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones

Answer (score 1):

Opting region near by is one way to get  good network performance and low latency. Also if you choose multi region you will get high availability along with better performance it's involved cost more. Choose defense on  criticality of application.